# C++ first sleeps than "couts"

Tags: c++, sleep

I am just learning c++ and been playing with sleep() function, this is my code

```
#include<iostream>
#include<unistd.h>
using namespace std;
int main(){
cout << "...";
sleep(5)
cout << "\nLorem Ipsum"
}
```

instead of output being

```
...
```

and than after five seconds

```
Lorem Ipsum
```

instead I get five second wait first and than this is printed all at once

```
...
Lorem Ipsum
```

Comment: `cout` is most probably buffered.

Comment: use `cout << "..." << std::flush;`

Comment: Try to only show code that compiles (so please copy paste code you actually compiled at least once). This snippet you posted obviously does not..

Comment: Most consoles are line-buffered, so if you were to put the `\n` on the `...` bit it would probably work like you expect too. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should `flush()` `cout` explicitly (or use `std::endl`) to force immediate output

```
int main() {
    cout << "...";
    cout.flush(); // Flush explicitly
    sleep(5):
    cout << "\nLorem Ipsum";
}
```

The text will not be written to `std::cout`, unless the underlying buffer has reached a certain watermark filling, or `std::flush()` is called (`std::endl` does so implicitly).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It fixes the problem and I also researched buffer a little.

Comment: @BenVoigt THX a lot for your improvements, I'm not a native speaker, have a tricky keyboard, and typing drunk most of the time ;-).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: Ahh, some people are more defensive about such things than others.  I'll try to remember to go ahead and volunteer small improvements to your posts.

Comment: @BenVoigt THX a lot again. As long I'm sober enough, I behave the same way with other's posts I meet ;-) ...